# IE fails to load js on soft reload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asynchronous, requirejs

I'm having an issue just with IE, if I do a soft reload (which i define as just hitting f5 or the refresh button) all my javascript fails to load. If I do what I consider a hard refresh (selecting the address in the address bar and hitting return on the keyboard) the javascript all loads fine. It loads fine in all other browsers. Just IE11, no errors.

I'm using requirejs so loading everything async, if I put compatibility mode in IE10 and below I start to get errors, the lower I go the more errors but this doesn't explain the ie11 issue which is what I'm most concerned about.

Comment: do you have the dev tool opened when you press f5? Is the button for "Always refresh from server" on the networking tab of dev tools selected?

Comment: Hi Rob, I've tried it on and off and same result,

Comment: Hi Karl, can you provide a reproduction url? jsfiddle.net mashup? try following these debugging steps. 1. open about:blank, 2. display and PIN the dev tool to the about:blank tab, 3. Select the debug tab of the dev tool and select "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown (looks like a stop sign). 4. Select the Networking tab of dev tools and turn on "Always refresh from server" (looks like a floppy disk), and click the Start button. 5. Return to the IE address bar and navigate to your dev or production site by typing in the address.

Comment: Examine any break points risen. Post back with the output from the Console tab, Examine the Network stack, and the response codes of the requests to the script resources.Post back with the Networking list (select Copy from the context menu on the dev tool)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my requirejs call was to far up the page. I noticed in the debugger that it was loading all the js files from my main.js fine so didn't seem to be failing to load anything.

I put it as the last thing to be called just before closing head and it worked. Why this was only an issue with IE soft refresh I do not know, and makes me think there's perhaps something more that shouldn't be... But it did solve my problem!